# Pgfplots, Legend Color

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have the following problem: I Have a TikZ Picture with two data plots, each with a different color. I want each one to appear in the legend, and I'm using `\addlegendentry`. The problem is that Latex compiles it showing the same color (that of the first plot) for both legend entries. I can't manage to get it right. Any help is much appreciated!

Code Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]

\centering
%\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        %xlabel=Time,
        %ylabel=$\Delta Z$,
        %title={Arbitrage Decision},
        yticklabels={,,},
        xticklabels={,,},
        xmax=20,xmin=0, xtick={0}, ytick={0},
        ymin=-.8, ymax=0.8, width=\textwidth, height=8cm,
                     ]
        \addplot[red] 
            plot coordinates {
       (1,0)
       (2,0.119098372908416)
       (3,0.0587139912536361)
       (4,-0.27031374415238)
       (5,-0.321767788431161)
       (6,-0.311970267679964)
       (7,-0.321597306182755)
       (8,-0.290922789133446)
       (9,-0.295971286973468)
       (10,-0.287426203316645)
       (11,-0.306326196276815)
       (12,-0.493603624276272)
       (13,-0.274091233027778)
       (14,-0.355035567724277)
       (15,-0.307926381319453)
       (16,-0.3723808555904)
       (17,-0.465577005289438)
       (18,-0.499906424048013)
       (19,-0.580303015935037)
       (20,-0.541777724182955)


      };
      \addlegendentry{$\Delta Z$}
      %node[above] at (axis cs:1.5,95) {$S^E$};

        \addplot[color=black, style=dashed] 
                plot coordinates {
             (1,0)
             (2,0)
             (3,0)
             (4,0)
             (5,0)
             (6,0)
             (7,0)
             (8,0)
             (9,0)
             (10,0)
             (11,0)
             (12,0)
             (13,0)
             (14,0)
             (15,0)
             (16,0)
             (17,0)
             (18,0)
             (19,0)
             (20,0)

            };



 \end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}


\captionsetup{format=hang, justification=justified, width=\textwidth}
\vspace{.1cm}
\caption*{\textbf{Panel A}: Sample Brownian Motion where $\Delta Z = \xi\sqrt{\Delta t}$; $\Delta t = 1/100$; $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
%xlabel=Time,
%ylabel=$\Delta Z$,
%title={Arbitrage Decision},
yticklabels={,,},
xticklabels={,,},
xmax=20,xmin=0, xtick={0}, ytick={0},
ymin=-.1, ymax=0.3, width=\textwidth, height=8cm,legend pos = north west]
\addplot[green] coordinates {
(1,0)
(2,0.0250244632386685)
(3,0.0554593278345405)
(4,0.0654368471373184)
(5,0.0522393053079004)
(6,0.056302957955299)
(7,0.0818373899525913)
(8,0.123643822846327)
(9,0.12530090609606)
(10,0.0892209109976901)
(11,0.071957710134649)
(12,0.0495597874988943)
(13,0.0578078951199786)
(14,0.0687186416973062)
(15,0.123940519634878)
(16,0.103015291916538)
(17,0.134159762952377)
(18,0.142495182864937)
(19,0.0874592151837793)
(20,0.014181052418952)

};
\addlegendentry{GWP1}


\addplot[green] coordinates {
(1,0)
(2,0.003)
(3,0.0045)
(4,0.006)
(5,0.0075)
(6,0.009)
(7,0.0105)
(8,0.012)
(9,0.0135)
(10,0.015)
(11,0.0165)
(12,0.018)
(13,0.0195)
(14,0.021)
(15,0.0225)
(16,0.024)
(17,0.0255)
(18,0.027)
(19,0.0285)
(20,0.03)

};


\addplot[blue] coordinates {
(1,0)
(2,-0.00853956850990679)
(3,-0.0171870248806746)
(4,-0.00548447253631596)
(5,0.00638491029571863)
(6,-0.0090966989367963)
(7,-0.000609747128328755)
(8,-0.00399157731385536)
(9,-0.00187457451809036)
(10,0.00420956011895954)
(11,0.0031221460646704)
(12,0.01260938678132)
(13,0.007824297608025)
(14,-0.00220727508765742)
(15,0.00554351691044548)
(16,0.0175169914115017)
(17,0.0174718949520942)
(18,0.0151757561241811)
(19,0.026384528315795)
(20,0.027525749190792)

};      
\addlegendentry{GWP2}


\addplot[blue] coordinates {
(1,0)
(2,0.001)
(3,0.0015)
(4,0.002)
(5,0.0025)
(6,0.003)
(7,0.0035)
(8,0.004)
(9,0.0045)
(10,0.005)
(11,0.0055)
(12,0.006)
(13,0.0065)
(14,0.007)
(15,0.0075)
(16,0.008)
(17,0.0085)
(18,0.009)
(19,0.0095)
(20,0.01)

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionsetup{format=hang, justification=justified, width=\textwidth}
\vspace{.1cm}
\caption*{\textbf{Panel A}: Sample Brownian Motion where $\Delta Z = \xi\sqrt{\Delta t}$; $\Delta t = 1/100$; $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Ok, here is a directly compilable code. I have truncated the series so it wouldn't be so long. If I compile this, on the second (lower) TikZ the legend for GWP1 and GWP2 is green. 
Hope this helps clarify my problem.

Comment: When I turn this into a compilable example (with some dummy data), I get the correct colours in the legend and the plots. Could you complete the example so it's directly compilable?

Comment: It also works with my slightly older pgfplots version from OpenSUSE TexLive. I don't see anything uncommon in the code either.

Comment: Is there a possibility the problem is not in the code itself but something else? Is it possible to specify the marker color in the legend directly?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found the answer. The problem seems to be that if I include other plots which not appear in the legend, TeX messes up. Once I put the plots with legend entries directly underneath each other and everything else at the end of the document it worked! Thanks for your support!

Comment: You don't have to put the plots with legend entries directly underneath each other. Instead, you can just add `forget plot` to the plots for which you don't want legend entries.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks, that is a really good tip! I've been struggeling with that and now my plots are not where they're supposed to be (in my logical order)!